# Providing Naming strict naming standards for Branch names

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, is there a way to give a naming standard to branch names like not allowing special characters etc. I did check and saw branch policies, but it's for a different purpose.

Can someone let me know if this feature is present or not?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are toggles to block branch names that are the same as existing branches (with casing being the only difference) and platform reserved names or incompatible characters, as seen below:

[image: Cross Platform Compatibility toggles for git repositories in Azure DevOps]

I'm not sure if this allows you to provide a custom naming standard via regex or template, but this should at least take care of the special characters scenario you were asking for.

To get to this setting, go to your project then click on the cog on the bottom left to get to the Project Settings area. From there, go to Code > Repositories > Git Repositories. Then, click on the Options tab to find these toggles.

You can also set these options per repo if you don't want to set them globally. Just click on the repo name instead of "Git Repositories".